# Session timeout not working in Cakephp 2

Tags: php, session, cakephp

I need to define a very large session time on a cakephp 2 application due to a business need. I defined it on the core.php file as follows:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
   'defaults'  => 'php', //defaults => php
   'cookie' => 'cookie',
   'timeout'   => 4320 // 3 days
));
```

I made a test and arround two hours of inactivity my session is closed, every time I click a button I get back to the logon screen, how can I effectively control my session time?

Comment: The first trouble-shooting step should be to verify the expiration time and other properties of the generated cookie. You should be able to obtain that information in any decent browser. Other important details are whether you share the session directory and application domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this It may work.it is working for me

core.php

```
 Configure::write('Session', array(
            'defaults' => 'php',
            'timeout' => 259200,
            'ini' => array(
                'session.gc_maxlifetime' => 259200 // 3 day
            )
    ));
```

Comment: In fact `session.gc_maxlifetime` defaults to `Configure::read('Session')['timeout'] * 60` (the former is in minutes, the latter in seconds).

Comment: Thanks, I tried this option and it worked as I expected.